# The 100 game - CanIWin()

Tags: java, game

**Problem:**

1. Two players pick numbers from a common pool of number to reach a combined total.
2. The player who get to reach/cross the target value wins.
3. The problem is to find out if player-1 can enforce a strategy to win - for a given total and a pool of numbers.

**My Approach:**

Assuming both the players pick the optimal number from the available pool.
By optimal, I mean -

1. Check if the highest number available in the pool >= remaining value. [yes]=> return the highest value available.
2. If winning is not possible, pick the highest available number (`RequiredToWin - HighestNumberInThePool`) in the pool that will NOT guarantee a win in the next turn.

I just came up with 'a' solution and wrote the code. I am trying to analyze if it is optimal, in terms of time, space. Also trying to understand how I can improve my coding conventions - Global variables and the way I am using the conditional statements. I need help-review to make the code better.

```
/* In "the 100 game," two players take turns adding, to a running 
total, any integer from 1..10. The player who first causes the running 
total to reach or exceed 100 wins. 
What if we change the game so that players cannot re-use integers? 
For example, if two players might take turns drawing from a common pool of numbers 
of 1..15 without replacement until they reach a total >= 100. This problem is 
to write a program that determines which player would win with ideal play. 

Write a procedure, "Boolean canIWin(int maxChoosableInteger, int desiredTotal)", 
which returns true if the first player to move can force a win with optimal play. 

Your priority should be programmer efficiency; don't focus on minimizing 
either space or time complexity. 
*/

    package Puzzles;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class The100Game{
        List<Integer> pool;
        int raceTo;

        The100Game(int poolMax, int finalSum){
            /*  If (finalSum > combined sum of all numbers). 
             *  This is an impossible problem to solve  
             */
            if(finalSum > ((poolMax*poolMax + poolMax)/2)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected sum cannot be achieved!");
            }

            raceTo = finalSum;
            pool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<poolMax;i++)
                pool.add(i+1);
        }

        /*  Autoplay the game with optimal mooves   */
        boolean canIWin(){
            int turns = 0;
            while(raceTo>0){
                turns++;
                System.out.println("Player"+( (turns%2==0)?"2":"1" )+" ==> "+pickANumber()+"   == Remaining ["+raceTo+"]");
            }
            return (turns%2==1);
        }

        /*  Pick an Optimal number, so to win 
         *  or prevent he opponent from winning 
         */
        int pickANumber(){
            int leastMax = -1;
            int len = pool.size();
            for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                int tmp = pool.get(i);
                if(tmp>=raceTo){
                    /*  Winning Pick */
                    pool.remove(i);
                    raceTo -= tmp;
                    return tmp; 
                }else{
                    if(leastMax > 0){
                        /*  Picking the highest number available in the pool might let the next player win. 
                         *  So picking a number < leastMax, if available - to gaurentee otherwise.  */
                        if(tmp < leastMax){
                            pool.remove(i);
                            raceTo -= tmp;
                            return tmp;
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
                    }   

                    if(i-1 >= 0) {
                        /*  We know, the highest number available in the pool is < raceTo (target sum)
                         *  Check in the pool 
                         *  if the sum of the highest number + nextHighest number >=  raceTo (target sum)
                         *      [True]  => Skip both the numbers and look for a number < the LeastMax 
                         *                   so the opposite player does not win.
                         *      [False] => The highest number in the pool is the best pick
                         */
                        if(tmp+pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
                            pool.remove(i);
                            raceTo -= tmp;
                            return tmp;
                        }else{
                            leastMax = raceTo - tmp;
                            i--;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }else{
                        pool.remove(i);
                        raceTo -= tmp;
                        return tmp;
                    }
                }
            }

            /*  The raceTo sum cannot be achieved in this turn.
             *  There is no number available in the pool 
             *  that can prevent a Win in the next turn. 
             *  So we return the highest number availble in the pool.
             */
            int tmp = pool.get(pool.size()-1);
            pool.remove(pool.size()-1);
            raceTo -= tmp;
            return tmp;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            The100Game game = new The100Game(15, 105);
            System.out.println("\nPlayer-"+(game.canIWin()?"1":"2")+" wins!");
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> --------------------------------------
> Player1 ==> 15   == Remaining [90]
> Player2 ==> 14   == Remaining [76]
> Player1 ==> 13   == Remaining [63]
> Player2 ==> 12   == Remaining [51]
> Player1 ==> 11   == Remaining [40]
> Player2 ==> 10   == Remaining [30]
> Player1 ==> 9   == Remaining [21]
> Player2 ==> 8   == Remaining [13]
> Player1 ==> 5   == Remaining [8]
> Player2 ==> 7   == Remaining [1]
> Player1 ==> 6   == Remaining [-5]
>
> Player-1 wins!
> ```

Comment: I've noticed that no one has posted an answer about the optimality of the heuristic. Once the code has been cleared up, should @CCP post a new question for that?

Answer (score 9):

## With regards to code quality...

Generally, you should add in a bit more whitespace to facilitate readability.

The initialization function looks fine to me. Good choice of `ArrayList` as a pool (and clever use of the `for` loop).

```
The100Game(int poolMax, int finalSum){
    /*  If (finalSum > combined sum of all numbers). 
     *  This is an impossible problem to solve  
     */
    if (finalSum > ((poolMax*poolMax + poolMax) / 2)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected sum cannot be achieved!");
    }

    raceTo = finalSum;
    pool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < poolMax; i++) {
        pool.add(i+1);
    }
}
```

In `canIWin()`, you should make use of string formatting instead of concatenation.

```
/*  Autoplay the game with optimal mooves   */
boolean canIWin() {
    int turns = 0;
    while (raceTo > 0) {
        turns++;
        System.out.printf(
            "Player %d ==> %d == Remaining [%d]\n",
            (turns % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 1,
            pickANumber(),
            raceTo
        );
    }
    return turns % 2 == 1;
}
```

You should do the same for your main function too.

As for your `pickANumber()` function, you should make your if branches "flatter". Your structure of the code inside the for loop looks like this:

```
if () {
} else {
    if () {
        if () {
        } else {
        }
    }   
    if () {
        if () {
        } else {
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

In many cases, you can replace `else { continue; }` by changing the structure of your `if` statement. I'll leave this as an exercise.

If we look closely, we can see that this particular piece of code appears very frequently.

```
pool.remove(i);
raceTo -= tmp;
return tmp;
```

This can be easily thrown into a seperate function and would make the code a lot cleaner.

EDIT: Thanks to @ambigram_maker for pointing out that I typed `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.printf`. My Java has been rusty (no pun intended) for a while.

Comment: Shouldn't you put `System. printf()` for outputting formatted strings?

Comment: @ambigram_maker Whoops, forgot about that. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @wei2912 Thank you for your review. I will keep in mind the suggestions. Very much appreciate your time. +1

Answer (score 8):

**Only focusing on `int pickANumber()`**

Let us take a look at the `if..else......` **beast** with comments removed

```
if(tmp>=raceTo){
    pool.remove(i);
    raceTo -= tmp;
    return tmp; 
}else{
    if(leastMax > 0){
        if(tmp < leastMax){
            pool.remove(i);
            raceTo -= tmp;
            return tmp;
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }   
    if(i-1 >= 0) {
        if(tmp+pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
            pool.remove(i);
            raceTo -= tmp;
            return tmp;
        }else{
            leastMax = raceTo - tmp;
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }else{
        pool.remove(i);
        raceTo -= tmp;
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

to get a better overview, we will use the last part of [wei1912](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29611/wei2912)'s answer and extract the repeating part to a spearate method.

```
private int pickTheNumber(int poolIndex){
    int pickedValue = pool.remove(poolIndex);
    raceTo -= pickedValue;
    return pickedValue;
}
```

now our `if..else` will look like

```
if(tmp>=raceTo){
    return pickTheNumber(i); 
}else{
    if(leastMax > 0){
        if(tmp < leastMax){
            return pickTheNumber(i);
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }   
    if(i-1 >= 0) {
        if(tmp + pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
            return pickTheNumber(i);
        }else{
            leastMax = raceTo - tmp;
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }else{
        return pickTheNumber(i);
    }
}
```

mhhh, that does look a lot better. But we can still do better.

Each time we have a `if` with an `else` and if we return a value or calling `continue` inside the `if block`, we can simply skip the `else`. So lets refactor !

```
if(tmp>=raceTo){
    return pickTheNumber(i); 
}
if(leastMax > 0){
    if(tmp < leastMax){
        return pickTheNumber(i);
    }
    continue;
}   
if(i-1 >= 0) {
    if(tmp + pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
        return pickTheNumber(i);
    }
    leastMax = raceTo - tmp;
    i--;
    continue;
}
return pickTheNumber(i);
```

Oh yeah, this looks neat.

Now let us rename this ugly `tmp` to `currentValue` and also let us move the declaration outside of the loop and we get

```
int pickANumber(){
    int currentValue = -1;
    int leastMax = -1;
    int len = pool.size();
    for(int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--){
        currentValue = pool.get(i);
        if(currentValue >= raceTo){
            return pickTheNumber(i); 
        }
        if(leastMax > 0){
            if(currentValue < leastMax){
                return pickTheNumber(i);
            }
            continue;
        }   
       if(i-1 >= 0) {
            if(currentValue + pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
                return pickTheNumber(i);
            } 
            leastMax = raceTo - currentValue ;
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        return pickTheNumber(i);
    }
    return pickTheNumber(pool.size()-1);
}
```

**Update**
After seeing [h.j.k](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/27975/h-j-k)'s great [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64425/29371) to flatten the `if` statements I tried to expand on it.

**h.j.k's result**

> ```
> private int pickANumber() {
>     int leastMax = -1;
>     for (int i = pool.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // note: removed 'len' variable
>         int currentValue = pool.get(i).intValue();
>         if (currentValue >= raceTo || leastMax > 0 || i == 0
>                 || currentValue + pool.get(i - 1).intValue() < raceTo) {
>             if (leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax) {
>                 continue;
>             }
>             return pickTheNumber(i);
>         } else if (currentValue + pool.get(i - 1).intValue() >= raceTo) {
>             leastMax = raceTo - currentValue;
>             i--;
>         }
>     }
>     return pickTheNumber(pool.size() - 1);
> }
> ```

But it hasn't been suitable enough to get rid of the deepest `if` statment

> ```
>             if (leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax) {
>                 continue;
>             }
> ```

If you are interrested check the history.

But now just let us start here

```
if(leastMax > 0){
    if(currentValue < leastMax){
        return pickTheNumber(i);
    }
    continue;
}
```

Based on the fact that `currentValue >= 1` for each item of `pool`, we can skip the check for `lestMax > 0`.
Because if `leastMax <= 0` the condition `currentValue < leastMax` would never be true. So if we revert the condition which reaches the continue `(leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax)` to `currentValue < leastMax`

This will change the top most `if` condition to

```
if (currentValue >= raceTo
      || (currentValue < leastMax) {

    return pickTheNumber(i);
}
```

No let us see, when the `continue` would be reached  as we need avoid this

```
if(leastMax > 0){
    if(currentValue < leastMax){
        return pickTheNumber(i);
    }
    continue;
}
```

as we see only if `leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax`

if (leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax){
        continue;
    }

to prevent leaking the `continue` into the `if` part we will add a new condition

```
if (currentValue >= raceTo
      || (currentValue < leastMax) 
      || leastMax <= 0 {

    return pickTheNumber(i);
}
```

the next condition to check is

```
   if(i - 1 >= 0) {
        if(currentValue + pool.get (i -1) < raceTo){
            return pickTheNumber(i);
        } 
        leastMax = raceTo - currentValue ;
        i--;
        continue;
    }
```

we see our next condition to integrate:

if `(i - 1 >= 0)` which is equal to `i > 0` and also `currentValue + pool.get (i -1) < raceTo` is true we need to pick a number.

```
if (currentValue >= raceTo
      || (currentValue < leastMax) 
      || (leastMax <= 0 
            && i > 0 
            && currentValue + pool.get (i -1) < raceTo){

    return pickTheNumber(i);
}
```

the `else` or better `else if` part is easy

```
 else if (leastMax <= 0 && i > 0) {
    leastMax = raceTo - currentValue;
    i--;
}
```

the complete method

```
int pickANumber() {
    int currentValue;
    int leastMax = -1;
    int len = pool.size();
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentValue = pool.get(i);

        if (currentValue >= raceTo
                || (currentValue < leastMax)
                || (leastMax <= 0
                    && (i > 0) 
                    && (currentValue + pool.get(i - 1)) < raceTo)) {

            return pickTheNumber(i);

        } else if (leastMax <= 0 && i > 0) {
            leastMax = raceTo - currentValue;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return pickTheNumber(pool.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: `int pickedValue = pool.get(poolIndex); pool.remove(poolIndex);` this can be combined into the final statement, as the return value of `remove` is the `get` value.

Comment: @h.j.k., Thanks. I didn't check this, as I have tested it in C# ;-) Updated my answer.

Comment: I wonder if the multiple if statements could be flattened. I haven't taken a close look at this part of the code to determine if there'll be any negative side effects from doing so.

Comment: @wei2912, I tried it 5 minutes ago and saw :-( . You can check the history.

Comment: @Heslacher Very much appreciate your time. I should have seen it coming - the beast/messy if/else conditions in my code.

+1

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to build upon the two answers provided by @wei2912 and @Heslacher and *attempt to flatten the `if` statements*.

Let's assume we have the method `pickTheNumber` in @Heslacher's answer. Looking at the somewhat simplified logic:

```
    if(currentValue >= raceTo){
        return pickTheNumber(i); 
    }
    if(leastMax > 0){
        if(currentValue < leastMax){
            return pickTheNumber(i);
        }
        continue;
    }   
   if(i-1 >= 0) {
        if(currentValue + pool.get(i-1) < raceTo){
            return pickTheNumber(i);
        } 
        leastMax = raceTo - currentValue;
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    return pickTheNumber(i);
```

We can identify the four cases where we `return pickTheNumber(i)`:

1. `currentValue >= raceTo`
2. `leastMax > 0 && currentValue < leastMax`^
3. `currentValue + pool.get(i - 1) < raceTo`
4. The final `return`

First, the final `return pickTheNumber(i)` is only reached when `! (i - 1 >= 0)`, i.e. `! (i >= 1)`, i.e. `i = 0`.

This roughly allows us to chain the four comparisons as such (note that I am also calling `intValue` to get around the autoboxing):

```
if (currentValue >= raceTo || leastMax > 0 || i == 0
        || currentValue + pool.get(i - 1).intValue() < raceTo) { ... }
```

Now, I put a (^) on the second condition, and you see that we only compare `leastMax > 0` above. That is because according to your logic, we will `continue` on our loop when `leastMax > 0 && ! (currentValue < leastMax)`, and this will bypass the comparison of the two largest numbers with `raceTo` too. As such, our first statement inside the 'super' `if` statement will be the condition to `continue` (note how I turn the meaning of 'not lesser' as 'greater than or equals'):

```
if (leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax) {
    continue;
}
```

Now, by right, we need to negate our first condition to make sure we only `continue` when it is the second condition that has been satisfied. However, if you look at the computation of `leastMax`, it is always positive when `remaining > current`, which so happens (?) to be the negation of the first condition. In other words, when the second condition is `true`, we already know that the first condition must be `false`. Explicit negation of the first condition is thus unnecessary.

The second and final statement is just to `return pickTheNumber(i)`.

If we are not `return`-ing `pickTheNumber(i)`, then that means we should check whether we need to perform the following two steps:

```
leastMax = raceTo - currentValue;
i--;
```

This will go into its own `else if`. The final `pickANumber()` method in full:

```
private int pickANumber() {
    int leastMax = -1;
    for (int i = pool.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // note: removed 'len' variable
        int currentValue = pool.get(i).intValue();
        if (currentValue >= raceTo || leastMax > 0 || i == 0
                || currentValue + pool.get(i - 1).intValue() < raceTo) {
            if (leastMax > 0 && currentValue >= leastMax) {
                continue;
            }
            return pickTheNumber(i);
        } else if (currentValue + pool.get(i - 1).intValue() >= raceTo) {
            leastMax = raceTo - currentValue;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return pickTheNumber(pool.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 Great answer. I have expanded yours to get rid of the last `if` statement.

Comment: @Heslacher I tried to run your solution by using only `currentValue < leastMax` but the steps taken for the question is different... :-| This also riddled me for quite a while yesterday, before I ended with my solution. Either the more flattened form is actually the more ideal implementation (yay), or there's something we missed...

Comment: I have checked it and refactored it. Now it does what it is suposed to do ;-)

Comment: @Heslacher now I wish I can give you +2 for your answer. :)